# ILR/US citizen: £18.6k threshold not met by wife's pension

Tags: united-kingdom, us-citizens

When I retire I plan to stay in UK with my British wife (already retired) but her pension doesn't meet the threshold.  My pension will be good, but will the threshold rule be applied to deny me leave to remain?  Have worked here for visiting forces for 15 out of past 26 years, we've no children, our home's paid for.  Have tried to penetrate the government site without success, so if anyone can help, I'd be grateful.  (Solicitor appointment next week.) Would dual citizenship present the same barriers?  Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: There was a recent court case that, if I understood correctly, will lead to the foreign spouse's income being included in the means calculation.

Comment: I have the impression it is inconceivable for British authorities that a bloody foreigner might actually have higher income than the British citizen they want to live with in the UK. Or any income at all.

Comment: Have you looked at the [UK guidance to extend your stay as a retired person of independent means](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/extend-your-stay-as-a-retired-person-of-independent-means/extend-your-stay-as-a-retired-person-of-independent-means), particularly as you can demonstrate the close connection